# How to correctly pass in JavaScript object to Rails back-end through HTTP headers?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to pass in header information from the JavaScript to a Rails back-end using AJAX, and I can't seem to correctly get the data of `user`.

Example, I have the following code:

```
var user_id = '114';
var headers = { user: { latitude: 37.3382, longitude: -121.8863 }, test: 'testing'};
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/' + user_id,
  headers: headers
});
```

On the Ruby on Rails back-end, I can access the `test` key just fine using `request.headers['test']`. It will give me exactly the value I expect, `"testing"`.

However, when I try to access the `user` key through `request.headers['user']`, I get the value of `"[object Object]"`. This is not what I want, I want to be able to get a user's `latitude` and `longitude` values.

I have tried `request.headers['user']['latitude']` and `request.headers['user']['longitude']`, and in both cases I get a result of `nil`.

My question is, how can I modify the above code in order to be able to correctly access a user's latitude and longitude on the back-end from the HTTP Headers?

I've read countless Stack Overflow questions but this is the closest I have been able to get!

Comment: Try something like `request.headers['user']['latitude']` or `request.headers['user']['longitude']`

Comment: Just tried, I get `nil` :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var user_id = '114';
var headers = { user: JSON.stringify({ latitude: 37.3382, longitude: -121.8863     }), test: 'testing'};
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/' + user_id,
  headers: headers
});
```

Then on the ruby side use JSON.parse to recover the object.

Comment: I would change it to `var headers = JSON.stringify({ user: { latitude: 37.3382, longitude: -121.8863     }, test: 'testing'});`

Comment: This worked! But, it sounds like I have to call `JSON.stringify` for each nested object. Is there a better way to handle this for nested objects, rather than calling `JSON.stringify` on every single nested object?


@BrunoRomaszkiewicz I tried that and the header doesn't recognize either the `user` or `test` keys >.<. Both give me `nil`

Comment: Why not use a POST and post the data as data instead of headers? Also you could store it in the session cookie and it would be automatically passed in the header for each request.

Comment: From my understanding, POST requests are typically used by forms and when adding data to the database? On this users page, I'm retrieving a user's profile (and thus, a user's data) and am calculating how far away that user is to the current user who is viewing the profile (hence, the latitude and longitude values). Perhaps I should consider using the session cookie since that seems like a viable alternative

Comment: Ahh in that case i would suggest just passing the lat/long as a query string parameter to the GET request. You can just append '?lat=37.33&lon=-121.55&test=testing' to the url and the parameters will be in the params hash in your controller server side.

Comment: HTML headers are not usually used to transport application data, more for technical things like API negotiation and session/cookie transport.

Comment: Thanks @dinomix for the answer and comments! I actually wanted to do that, but I was told yesterday that it's common practice (?) to pass data from front-end to back-end using `headers` (specifically for GET requests). But, for POST, `data` is typically used. If you or anyone has an opinion on this, please share because I always used URL parameters (like you suggested) before I was told this :)

Comment: The GET query string and POST body are common ways to pass application data, this is what they were designed for. HTML headers are for protocol negotiation, cache control, and other meta data, you wouldn't usually use those for application data.

Comment: Thanks again, not sure how to upvote comments, otherwise you'd have more 1s next to your comments!